# Joomla / Add category description to Article Category modules

Tags: joomla, module

How can I add **category description** to Article Category modules in Joomla?
The only php call after grouping items is `<?php echo $group_name; ?>`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but for Joomla! 3.5 and higher you can use...

```
$category   = JCategories::getInstance('Content')->get($item->catid);
```

Much easier than doing a call to the database in your template override files.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your default.php override.

```
<?php 
    $db = &JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $id = JRequest::getString('id'); 
    $db->setQuery('SELECT #__categories.description FROM #__content, #__categories WHERE #__content.catid = #__categories.id AND #__content.id = '.$id); 
    $category = $db->loadResult();
    echo $category; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in your default.php override or custom template:

```
<?php // tested in Joomla 3.1.5 only
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $idbase = $params->get('catid');
    $catID =  $idbase[0];
    //echo $catID;
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery("SELECT description FROM #__categories WHERE id = ".$catID." LIMIT 1;");
    $catDesc = $db->loadResult();
?>
<div class="catdesc">
    <?php echo $catDesc; ?>
</div>
```

Modified from:
http://www.noxidsoft.com/development/get-the-category-blog-description-in-joomla-3-1-5/

Comment: It's better to use `$db->q("$catID")` to quote the value and `$params->getInt('catid')` to avoid injections.

Answer (score 0):

So in: /modules/mod_articles_category/default.php

make sure you create an over ride first, but then add:

```
$db     = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('id', 'title', 'description'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('extension') . ' = ' . $db->quote('com_content'));
$db->setQuery($query);

$categories = $db->loadObjectList('id');
```

just after: defined('_JEXEC') or die;

Then in each item you can load it in like:

```
echo $categories[$item->catid]->description;
```

If using on the grouping rather than item, it's a little different and here is the whole top snippet replacement:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_articles_category
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2019 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$db     = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('id', 'title', 'description'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('extension') . ' = ' . $db->quote('com_content'));
$db->setQuery($query);

$categories = $db->loadObjectList('title');

?>
<ul class="category-module<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?> mod-list">
    <?php if ($grouped) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($list as $group_name => $group) : ?>     
            <li>
            <div class="mod-articles-category-group"><?php echo JText::_($group_name); ?></div>
            <p><?php echo count($group) > 0 ? $categories[$group_name]->description : ''; ?></p>
```

Because $group doesn't contain anything but the list, we get the name instead this time and load the categories from the name.